# jQuery UI Draggable Dragging Below Absolute Positioned Items

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-position, jquery-ui-draggable

I am building a jQuery interface that uses the draggable feature of the jQuery UI. For the most part, this works excellent, except whenever I drag an object over elements that have absolute positioning. Instead of appearing above the absolutely positioned items, the dragged object appears below.

You can find a fiddle of this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/nTdrG/2/, or download relevant part of the project here: http://box.com/webuploads.

Could someone please help me work around this issue?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a z-index to your style:

```
span {
    display: block;
    background-color: #0F0;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason that is not working when I apply it to my application. Any other ideas? :(

Comment: Did tried to increase the z-index value? Does the other block have a z-index value?

Comment: Hmmm... no it does not. Here is a work-in-progress version of the dragger application: http://www.box.com/webuploads . Would you mind having a look at it?

Comment: Just had a quick look for now and i wasn't able to find a solution. In the meanwhile you can try to use the [stack](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-stack) option

Answer (score 0):

You can also add zIndex to the draggable helper, so that it stays "above" everything else on the page as it moves.
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-zIndex